# selenium not get http

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried below code in eclipse. When I run this code firefox will open but driver.get("https://www.easybooking.lk/login");    not working. Please help me in resolving this error

```
package login;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class easylogin {

    //public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            //Object webdriver;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\jjpppp\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");

            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://www.easybooking.lk/login");
```

I am getting below error. How can I fix this? I added selenium firefox drivers

```
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:185)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.implicitlyWait(RemoteWebDriver.java:872)
    at login.easylogin.main(easylogin.java:20)
```

Comment: It seems implicitlyWait not working. Just comment this code and check once
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: hey thz its work pls post as a answer

Comment: Posted as an answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47029756/selenium-not-get-http/47030073#47030073

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per error message, it seems there is some problem in implicitlyWait. It does not seems to be working. Just comment this code and check once

> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to change the path to your driver
in the following way:

```
D:\\jjpppp\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe
```

You might also have a look at the following change in order to be sure that your DOM is completely loaded:

```
WebDriverWait logWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
logWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));  
driver.findElement(...)
```

Comment: same problem :(

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because your browser and geckodriver are not compatible.

I tried with latest firefox version(56.0) and geckodriver 18. It worked fine.

Then I tried firefox(56.0) and geckodriver 17. It gave me similar issue.

So better use latest firefox and geckodriver.

Answer (score 1):

try putting implicit wait after navigating to web address.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //Object webdriver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\jjpppp\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.easybooking.lk/login");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

this will help you to wait till web-page loads next find element.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

remove this and try